# How to specify --no-print-directory within the Makefile itself

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to run my makefile without the -w flag turned on by the recursive make calls.
The flag to do that is --no-print-directory on the make command line.

Is it possible to specify that flag within the makefile itself?

I plan to make this flag dependent on a VERBOSE mode, perhaps something like

```
$(if $(VERBOSE),,MAKEFLAGS += no-print-directory))
```

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, just appending `--no-print-directory` to `MAKEFLAGS` should be enough, but you have to do that with [conditional directives](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax), not with [conditional functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions):

```
ifndef VERBOSE
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory
endif
```

Comment: This is because [variable assignment](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting) can't occur within an expansion which in turn is due to [how Make parses makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Contents). The only way to include variable assignment (or something else like rule definition) into an expandable code (`$(if ...)` in your question) is [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) function. But particularly for your case a simple conditional directive is ok and also clearer than `eval`.

Comment: Oh, and of course you can embed a conditional function into the variable assignment like this: `MAKEFLAGS += $(if $(value VERBOSE),,--no-print-directory)`. Here the assignment is performed unconditionally, but in case when `VERBOSE` is not defined or empty nothing is actually appended to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `.SILENT:` special target in the calling makefile.  For example, here's your toplevel makefile:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -f sub.mk foo

.SILENT:
```

and the submake makefile, sub.mk:

```
foo:
    @echo done
```

Note that [`.SILENT` is considered obsolete](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Targets), so it may not be around forever, and also note that including that in your makefile *also* has the effect of suppressing command echo, just as if you had put `@` before every command in the makefile.